# Determine whether the functional sequence is pointwise convergent

Tags: real-analysis

Determine whether the functional sequence is pointwise convergent. In the case of convergence, give the limit function and show that the convergence is uniform or that it is not uniform, as the case may be.

$$\Big(\tanh(n \cos(\tfrac{x}{n}) \Big)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \quad \quad (x\in \mathbb{R})$$

The definition of pointwise convergent states $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$. Using this $n \cos(\frac{x}{n})\to \infty$ and $\tanh(n \cos(\frac{x}{n}))\to1$?

This is the start of my solution no idea if I am on the right track.

Comment: Your arguments are fine and your solution is right! However, maybe you should argue more detailed: Why $n \cos(\frac{x}{n})\to \infty$ and $\tanh(n \cos(\frac{x}{n}))\to1$ hold?

Comment: Using my current solution does this then mean that it is pointwise convergent? and also how would I show if it would then be uniform or not? Thanks @p4sch

Comment: Yes, you show that the convergence is pointwise. Your argument can be modified to show locally uniform convergence. However, the convergence cannot be uniform. (Why?)

Comment: Is it because $|f_n(x)-f(x)| \to 0$? the \to is meant to have a strike through it dont know how to write it though. thanks @p4sch